# MVC5 not binding date value

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm writing an MVC application with Typescript, Knockout and bootstrap.

I have a field which I've bound a bootstrap v3 datetimepicker to.

The binding looks like this:

```
$('.form-group input[type="datetime"]').datetimepicker({ locale: 'en-GB' });
```

I have two issues with this for some reason.

1. No matter what I set for `locale` the input field always seems to render the date as US format.

[image: US Date format]

2. No matter how I try to post the value back, the MVC model binder doesn't see the value.

I'm less worried about #1 unless it's causing #2, I've tried to post the date value direct in knockout, this gives me a `/Date(1439838919784)/` value which MVC doesn't seem to like.

After that, I've tried converting the date value to a simple ticks representation by replacing the date bits of the string, creating a JavaScript date object and posting that:

```
var koDate = this.BetDetailsViewModel().Event.Date();            
var dateString = new Date(parseInt(koDate.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""), 10));
```

This gives me a value like this: `Mon Aug 17 2015 20:15:19 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)` which MVC also doesn't seem to pick up.

Finally, seeing as the bootstrap datetimepicker uses moment.js I thought I'd try to create a moment object from the date and post that. I popped the KO viewmodel property into a `moment()` ctor like this:

```
var momentDate = moment(this.BetDetailsViewModel().Event.Date()).format();
```

This gives me a value like this: `2015-08-17T20:23:34+01:00` which MVC seems to like.

Whilst technically I've just managed to solve the second issue it seems like I'm having to work harder than I should!

Is there some way I can circumvent the need to create a moment from the KO observable?

Also, why doesn't the locale seem to work as I'm expecting? the docs on the datetimepicker are pretty lean!

**EDIT**

Just for clarification, this is what I'm including script wise, in this order:

[image]

Comment: That is not Knockout way to bind a widget to a field. See https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/#manual for a bindingHandler.

Comment: Thanks for the link Roy, I did look over the bindingHandlers documents but whilst it is an improvement to the ways things are working there isn't a sensible guide for a TypeScript implementation and I've not had time to work it out from scratch yet. It doesn't seem to address point 1 though.

Comment: Have you tried 'en-gb' instead of 'en-GB'? `moment.locale('en-GB')` returns the latter, and docs suggest that's what it takes. https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#locale

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately 'en-gb' doesn't change the input value either. 
I'm using an <input type='date'/> so I wonder if I can do something in the native control and let the browser handle it.

Comment: Chrome will hijack the input field to use their own calendar picker with `type="date"`. `en-gb` is the proper `locale` option to use. Did you include the `moment-with-locales.js` or the `en-gb.js` file?

Comment: @Eonasdan I've included a whole raft of bits at the moment (in this order)
bootstrap-datepicker.min.js, moment.min.js, bootstrap-datepicker.en-GB.min.js, moment-with-locales.min.js, bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js.

I'm afraid I couldn't find a sensible description of the dependencies of the picker on moment, or moment and it's locales and wasn't even sure if the datetimepicker needed the datepicker etc etc. Any dependency description would be really helpful. I'm not getting any errors from the current setup, but am aware something could be overwritten in the wrong place.

Comment: @dougajmcdonald please check http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/#minimal-requirements

Comment: @Eonasdan Yeah that's what I was working from, unfortunately I can't seem to get things to work out, I've updated the question with my current scripts, I will include the locale script after those and see what happens

Comment: @Eonasdan ok, I might be getting somewhere, including the script with the locale specific 'en-GB.js' script gives me the console error, cannot read property 'dates' of undefined. Looking at the minified code, that points to this section: a.fn.datepicker.dates["en-GB"]. This to me suggests I either need to include the datepicker.min.js file as well as the datetimepicker.min.js file, or that I have some crappy datetime picker version maybe? It was the default one from NuGet, kind of expected it to work out of the box!

Comment: Are you using this package `Bootstrap.v3.Datetimepicker.CSS`? If not, it's not my picker. :)

Comment: Looks like I have the less version, but it's got your name on it! :P 

I do also have installed the bootstrap datepicker package, reckon it's worth removing that, and the less version and just going for the css on its own?

Comment: Oh wow, facepalm :s I thought I was getting my locale parameter from the '$(".date").datetimepicker({ locale: "en-gb" });' call in my TypeScript file...forgetting I'd put the bindingHandlers in for Knockout.
I took out the jQuery call direct, noticed I was still getting the picker and then remembered I had the KO binding, I put the locale in as the 'datePickerOptions' and it works like a charm :( Sorry for all the hassle.